# Django save() overriding, best practice: on model, form or view?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I've been succesfully hashing my custom user model's passwords by overriding the `save()` function like this:

```
def save(self, commit = True): 
    user = super(RegisterForm, self).save(commit = False)
    user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user
```

But I've placed this override on my register form definition, and it just occured to me that I could also do this in the User model definition, or in my `register()` view.

Is there a "correct" place to override these functions, like `clean()` or `save()`? Is there any practical difference?

ps: I'm not interested on using Django's default password-change and register views or forms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Upon digging in the source code I found the ModelForm's `save()` method to be calling the Model's(Model Instance) `save()` method. Check it [here.](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L442)

Now it is clear that first ModelForm's `save()` is called and within it(depending upon the commit value) Model's `save()` is called.

Also it's worth noting that in the code:

```
def save(self, commit = True): 
    user = super(RegisterForm, self).save(commit = False)
    user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
    #When you're hashing and setting the password to the user variable,
    #this user variable is a Model Object but is not saved in the database yet. 
    if commit:
        user.save()
        #Now in the above line you're ultimately calling the save method of Model instance.
    return user
```

So the question comes down to you.

Do you want to go one more step above in the abstraction layers(by overriding Model instance's save method) of django models?

Do you actually have a need to do it?

**Abstraction is one of the building block of OOPS.** So until a need arises which actually requires you to go above in the abstraction layers, why do it at all? **Clearly the password can be hashed in the ModelForm's `save()` method.**

Also, if you go a layer above in abstraction,
what if an unexpected behavior occurs in the future?

In my opinion, why not just leave it inside the ModelForm? We start from the highest layer of Abstraction when we start using django(we just call the methods and usually don't know what's happening in the classes we're inheriting; that's what oops is for) **and we go above only when a specific need arises.**

Hope this guides you in some way. Thanks.

Comment: I really appreaciate your research and time to answer this question. My reasoning about switching the override to the model definition comes from the fact that I will surely have to override some other `save()` functions eventually, and **they might be from models that do not depend upon any kind of form**, so it seems more organized to do all the overrides in a single place, as opposed to having them all over the code, on separate layers and separate Django elements. What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: Yes obviously. If there is a copious need of save methods for many models, then it would be neat to override save in the models only.(To have it all organized should always be a concern if a person is aiming for a big project). Although, I must add that you must be slightly more careful when in Model's Save method. It communicates with the database directly and a minute error might just bring a lot of headache. Besides this, I don't think that there should be any problem. After all if a "save" method is provided at  the Model level, then we shouldn't be too hesitant to use it.

Comment: Agreed. I'll mark your answer as good, between it and these comments I think we covered most of the issue.